# Border does not show up

Tags: css, border

My border is not showing up around my image, I'm not quite sure what the issue could be. I just need a small black border around the photo. My website is http://www.welovetile.com. I can't figure out what the problem could be. Thanks.

**CSS:**

```
#kitchen {
        height:250px;
        width:346px;
        background-image:url(images/kitchenbg.jpg);
    }

        #kitchen img
        {   
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            width: 316px;
            height: 228px;
            margin-top:11px;
            margin-left:15px;
            border-color:#000000;
            border-width:thin;
        }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="kitchen">
    <img src="images/kitchen.jpg" alt="Kitchen Tile Job"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 44):

Borders have three main pieces: a width, a style, and a color; the style is required for any of the others to work.

Try adding the style:

```
border-style: solid;
```

Also, you can specify all these in the same line of css:

```
border: thin solid black;
```

**Updated**

As pointed out by Wesley, border-style is the only required one.

From http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp :

*None of the border properties will have ANY effect unless the **border-style** property is set!*

Comment: Actually, `border-style` is the only necessary one, defaults are usually `thin/1px` and `#000` I believe: http://jsfiddle.net/xzbb3/

Comment: Actually, if you leave off the border color, it inherits the element's color.  In other words, if your text-color is pink, your border will be pink as well.  http://jsfiddle.net/xzbb3/1/

Comment: Thanks! I have a great deal to learn. This is my first website that I'm doing totally on my own.

Answer (score 7):

You're missing:

```
border-style: solid;
```

Answer (score 7):

You can put border width/style/color in one row like this:

```
Border: 1px solid black;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
border: 1px solid #F4F1E8;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #4C4843;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a border style property as well, for example `border-style: solid;`.